# mqtt async wait for messagse then respond to http post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, async-await, mqtt

I am new to node.js am trying to make a webhook, where I get an HTTP post request and want to send a request over mqtt and wait for mqtt messages in reference to the MQTT message and then send these messages a response over HTTP

```
  var array = [];
  const client = mqtt.connect(MQTTServer)
  var count =0;
  client.on('message', (topic, message) => {

  array[count] = message 
  count ++ 

  }

app.post('/tesr', function (request, response) {

    client.publish ('outTopic' , 'request ');
    client.subscribe('inTopic')


    //wait for multiple mqtt message in  MQTT callback 


    //after all messages received or timeout  return  here
     client.unsubscribe('inTopic')
    count = 0
    response.status(200).json(array);

  }
```

so have tried `while()` and `seInterval()` but haven't   found any sollution

Comment: You would need to create a promise for the next `inTopic` message, and `await` that. That you can do in a loop.

Comment: how to let the `client.on()` callback function triggering on message arrival and then trigger when all x number of messages are received or timeout if not

Comment: @saniljhaveri did you manage to do this for multiple requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `response.send(array)` from within the route handler, you can do it externally.

```
var array = [];
var resp;
var n = 10; //number of messages to wait for
var timeOutValue = 5000; //wait 5 seconds
var timer;

const client = mqtt.connect(MQTTServer)
var count =0;
client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
  array.push(message); 
  count ++ 
  if (count == n) {
     resp.send(array);
     client.unsubscribe('inTopic');
     resp = undefined;
     counter = 0;
     array = [];
     clearTimeout(timer)
  }
}

app.post('/test', function (request, response) {

resp = response;
client.publish ('outTopic' , 'request ');
client.subscribe('inTopic');

  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if (resp) {
        resp.send(array);
        resp = undefined;
        client.unsubscribe('inTopic');
        counter = 0;
        array = []
    }
  }, timeOutValue);

}
```

It's not pretty (and it's single call at a time...) but it should work.

Comment: Any particular reason for removing the accepted flag?

Comment: I am glad u ask using your solution  when the code is the `setTimeout()` it does not collect any callback MQTT messages  asynchronously so it returns nothing in  the response with this"Ignoring exception from a finished", I was able to get it going by using async-await but I had to deploy the code on firebase functions which runs node.js version 6.11.5 that does not support async-await so wanted to figure out a way to do it with just promise() but here the HTTP  session was completed without waiting for promise to be ready just like before

Comment: If you want to return the short list of received messages when the timeout is reached just edit the code in the timeout function to return them instead of the error

Comment: I've edited the answer to not raise and error on timeout but to send how ever many messages were received.

Comment: @hardillb I din't got what  (and it's single call at a time...) really means? Could you please explain? I am new to nodejs.

Comment: It can only handle a single HTTP request at a time (because there is only one global resp object)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable (such as `global.results={}` and in your `client.on('message', callback)` update the value with upcoming messages.

```
  client.on('message', (topic, mqttMessage) => {
    // mqttMessage is Buffer
    global.results.receiveResult = mqttMessage.toString();
    client.end();
  });
```

Now, in your API you can use a settimeout to return an appropriate response based on the value of global.results:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('printing results', global.results);
    if (global.results.publishResult !== 'Published Successfully') {
      return res
        .status(500)
        .send({ data: global.results, message: 'Publish Failed' });
    }
    if (!global.results.receiveResult) {
      return res
        .status(500)
        .send({ data: global.results, message: 'Published but Confirmation Not received' });
    }
    return res
      .status(200)
      .send({ data: global.results, message: 'Response from mqtt' });
  }, timeout);
```