# mqtt async wait for concurrent messages then respond to respective http post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, async-await, mqtt

I have this process for home automation project.

1. Receive message in HTTP request to my server.
2. Publish message in above step via MQTT topic to device.
3. Wait for 5 seconds to receive response from device via MQTT topic.
4. If response is received within 5 seconds the send success response ,
   else send error response, to original HTTP request in step 1

Below is the code taken from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986177/mqtt-async-wait-for-messagse-then-respond-to-http-post-request) since it matches with what exactly I am trying to do.

This code can handle only **one request** at a time. What should I do to handle **concurrent requests**?

```
var resp;
var timeOutValue = 5000; //wait 5 seconds
var timer;

const client = mqtt.connect(MQTTServer)

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
     resp.send(message);
     client.unsubscribe('inTopic');
     resp = undefined;
     clearTimeout(timer)
}

app.post('/test', function (request, response) {

resp = response;
client.publish ('outTopic' , 'request ');
client.subscribe('inTopic');

  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if (resp) {
        resp.send(message);
        resp = undefined;
        client.unsubscribe('inTopic');
    }
  }, timeOutValue);

}
```

I have tried this:

1. I am storing the HTTP request body in database and sending a unique
   id corresponding to the stored record to device in MQTT request.
2. This unique id is sent back in response from device.
3. When any message is received over MQTT, I check if unique id is
   present in database and retrieve the record if its present and send
   the response based on the request body present in record.
4. I wait for 5 seconds to get response from device otherwise I send
   error response to HTTP.

But I don't know whether it will work with concurrent requests because I am new to nodejs. *And all this happens within the http post route handler.*

Comment: Show us how you have tried to modify the code to make it support concurrent connections. If you want me to write this for you I can send you my consultancy rates.

Comment: Also this code doesn't do what you've asked, it is close, but it waits for 10 MQTT responses before replying.

Comment: @hardillb Since the code is too big, I can't copy it here. I am expecting only the steps to follow to handle such situations. Thanks.

Comment: The approach you outline is right, except you can't store the response object in a database because it has methods attached (and the socket handle to respond on) so it will have to be held in memory for the app

Comment: I don't store response object in database. I build response object based on request object, which is stored in database.

Comment: You need to keep hold of the response object passed to the post handler as that is the only ready to respond to the http request

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function scheduleMqtt() {
    var topic= 'office/csb_1';
    var topic1=topic;
    console.log("MQTT is started")
         var client = mqtt.connect(mqtturl, options);
         client.on('connect', mqtt_connect);
         function mqtt_connect() {
            console.log('client has connected successfully');
            client.subscribe(topic, 0, mqtt_subscribe);
            client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived);
            console.log(topic);
        };
        function mqtt_subscribe(err, granted) {
            console.log("Subscribed to " + topic);
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            console.log("Granted:")
            console.log(granted)
    
            client.publish(topic);
            console.log("topic");
            client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
                console.log(message.toString()); //if toString is not given, the message comes as buffer
            });       

        };
```

Comment: Answers should not just contain code, you need to add an explanation as to how/why this code solves the question that was asked. As it is I do not see how this code actually does anything useful.